# System.Data.RowNotInTableException

Tags: asp.net

i am facing System.Data.RowNotInTableException when i try to access KEY from a keyvaluepair insDelRowInfoList after deleting that particualar row from dataset which i saved in insDelRowInfoList.

```
 List<KeyValuePair<DataRow, String>> insDelRowInfoList = new List<KeyValuePair<DataRow, String>>();

 insDelRowInfoList.Add(new KeyValuePair<DataRow, string>(newDataSet.Tables[1].Rows[rowCount],"has been inserted"));

 foreach (KeyValuePair<DataRow, string> dataRow in insDelRowInfoList)
                        newDataSet.Tables[1].Rows.Remove(dataRow.Key);
```

plz help how to solve this issue.